# Selenium WebDriver clicking on hidden element

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, hidden-field

Hi I would like to know how to click on hidden element and/or disable element by using Selenium WebDriver.

I know with selenium 1 I can do this as below:

```
selenium.click(id="idOfHiddenField");
```

and this would work, but with selenium 2 (WebDriver), this doesn't. I do not want to use jquery to enable or show hidden fields , or JavaScript. This is because most of the test are using xpath.

Or do I just have to stay with old selenium which allows you to click on hidden fields?

Comment: WebDriver does not allow for interacting with hidden elements. It makes sense - user cannot click a hidden field so why your tests should be doing so?

Comment: Like JaceM mentioned go through the web flow like a normal user would. If a user has to click something to make that element visible then do it. There isn't much more I can say on this matter.

Comment: i want to be able to create fake data on test environment but through hidden field hacks.. also test against javascript turned off... etc.

Comment: A lot of jquery-ui widgets use hidden elements, which contain the real value being submitted.  Those jquery-ui widgets can be changed out, breaking all your tests, but if you test using the underlying element, your tests will continue to work.  I'm thinking CSS injection might be a way to force all the desired hidden elements visible.  But the test might look funny having two visible elements side-by-side for every jquery-ui widget.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a easier way to work around the problem using `JavascriptExecutor`.

For example:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('post-tag')[0].click();
```

The above javascript would click on the "Selenium" tag on the top right of this page (next to your question), even if it were hidden (hypothetically).

All you need to do is issue this JS instruction via the `JavascriptExecutor` interface like so:

```
(JavascriptExecutor(webdriver)).executeScript("document.getElementsByClassName('post-tag')[0].click();");
```

This would use the JS sandbox and synthetic click event to perform the click action. Although it defeats the purpose of WebDriver user activity simulation, you can use it in niche scenarios like in your case to good effect.

Comment: thanks, but most of them i have used xpath like //input[@value='xxx']

Comment: That's not by point. Any locator would locate any hidden element, XPath, CSS, id or whatever. I was suggesting you use JSExecutor to bypass WebDriver smartness. Did you try it? Did it work for you?

You can continue using XPath locator to locate a WebElement and pass it into the JS script which will click the passed-in element.

Answer (score 1):

there is one answer but multiple suggestions:

Answer: use selenium backed driver to click on the hidden element using something like

```java
Selenium selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, baseUrl);
selenium.clickAt("xpath=//area[@alt='Mercury']", clickPoint);
```

Suggestion 1: to create fake data specially if there's a lot to be created and you are looking for FOSS go for JMeter.

Suggestion2: to check javascript turned off disable javascript in the firefox instance itself e.g.

```java
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Js can be enabled by this  `:javascriptEnabled => true`  rite?

Answer (score 0):

It may not fit your needs, but another solution for some might be to alter the CSS for hiding an element.

Whilst Selenium *won't* find an element with `display: none;` it *will* find an element with the following:

```
.hide {
    position: absolute;
    top: -99em;
    left: -99em;
}
```

Then rather than using `jQuery.show/hide/toggle` in your app, you would use `jQuery.toggleClass('hide', true/false/unset_to_toggle)`.